# How to connect IdentityServer for a Java API

Tags: asp.net, jax-rs, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I need OpenID and OAuth 2.0 combined for one of my web based application which is written in Angular. API is written  in Java. So can I host IdentityServer 4.0 and connect that with my Java API and Angular front end?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IdentityServer4 is an open source OpenId Connect Framework built on .Net. So to answer your question if you can host it, the answer is yes you just need to make the implementation.

For your second question if Angular can connect to an OpenID Connect provider, yes it can. With for example this one [OIDC-Client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) .
If your API supports OIDC then yes it can use the tokens sent from the Angular app to authenticate the user.

Answer (score 1):

I created a repository https://github.com/lousaibiao/IdentityServer4ProtectSpringbootApi/ and it just a demo about how to config SpringBoot Api when it protected by IdServer. Wish it helps.